# How to call a bash script's function from node js?

Tags: node.js, bash

Trying to call a bash-scripts's function from another script written in NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a bash script in Node.js using `child_process`' `exec`

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('./yourscript.sh <args>',
  function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```